# Can you find me?

Tags: riddle

This is my first post.

> Unexpected, people hate me.
>   Some seek me.
>   I am found when others are not.
>   I am more than double what is wanted.

Can you find me?

Hint:

> I am something specific to the realm of the Internet.

Hint2:

> What people want is usually OK.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are

> a 404 page.

*Unexpected, people hate me.*

> A 404 page often appears unexpectedly when you were looking for something else, and it's usually annoying to find one since it means you can't get what you were looking for.

*Some seek me.*

> [Some people](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/60-really-cool-and-creative-error-404-pages/) have [created collections](http://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/best-404-pages-812505) of cool 404 pages.

*I am found when others are not.*

> A 404 page means "page not found" - it's found when other pages aren't.

*I am more than double what is wanted.*

> What is wanted ([apparently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success)) are the 200-and-something pages, which "indicate the action requested by the client was received, understood, accepted, and processed successfully." In particular, the 200 page (see Hint 2 below), and 404 is more than double 200.

Hint1:

> this whole idea is specific to the realm of the internet.

Hint2:

> what people usually want is [200 OK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success), the "[s]tandard response for successful HTTP requests". (Thanks to @wl for help with this one.)

Comment: Nonsense, everyone knows what you really want is a [418- I'm a teapot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).